# How do you open an external Vim editor containing the active Eclipse editor file

Tags: eclipse, vim

I'm not looking for an "Vim Plugin" for Eclipse. Instead, I'd just want a keyboard-shortcut to open the current Eclipse file within a new Vim instance.

Is there a quick and easy way to do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There's two ways to do this, the canonical way, and the hack. First:

### The Canonical Way

1. Window > Preferences... Fold out General > Editors > File Associations.
2. Choose the file type you want to edit
3. Click the "Add" button beside the "Associated editors" box.
4. Click "External programs" and "Browse...", then find gvim, or enter /usr/bin/gvim, or generally make it go to gvim.

Now, files of that type should show up in an external vim instance. Awesome, right? But that doesn't solve your problem of pushing the current buffer out to vim.

---

### The Hack

Instead, we're going to set vim as a "build tool", and have eclipse send it the current file as arguments. This may have some unaffected side-effects, based on your project settings, but look into them carefully if you experience things like unexpected re-building of your files.

1. Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration...
2. Select "Program" on the left and click the "New" icon.
3. Enter "Send to vim" for the Name
4. Enter "/usr/bin/gvim" (or whatever your path is) for the Location
5. Under "Working Directory" enter `${project_loc}` (this is a variable representing your project's top directory)
6. Under arguments enter `${resource_loc}` (this represents your current resource's path)
7. On the "Build" tab, un-check "Build before Launch" (unless you really want that)
8. On the Common tab, check "External Tools" under the "Display in favorites menu"

You should be all set! Now you can send your file to vim by using the menu

```
Run > External Tools > Send to vim
```

If you want to get fancy, you can even add a button to your toolbar.

*Be advised, I've used gvim in the examples. If you'd like to use terminal vim, you'll have to call it appropriately based on the terminal you're using. For xterm, this would be `/usr/bin/xterm -e /usr/bin/vim`, instead of `/usr/bin/gvim`*

Comment: Step 6. `--servername ECLIPSE --remote-tab "${resource_loc}"` will keep all files from eclipse in the same window instance

Comment: You can make a keyboard binding with 'The Hack' method from: Window -> Pref -> General -> Keys -> Run Last Launched External Tool

Comment: Both things that are totally valid and I didn't even think of. Good work Casey.

Comment: cool, thanks a lot for the tip!
BTW, I wouldn't call it a hack, it is using Eclipse as intended, isn't it? Casey, nice improvement, just let's add some quotes to support file names with blanks inside: --servername ECLIPSE --remote-tab "${resource_loc}"

Comment: Well, it's kind of a hack, since it's meant to be a run configuration (thus the necessity to tell it not to build) and the fact that eclipse refreshes the file with changed disk contents is really the only thing that makes it useful.

Comment: This along with Step 6 has worked very well for me.  Round-tripping seems to work very well.

Comment: Using `--remote-tab-silent` instead of `--remote-tab` eliminates the error message you get if you don't already have a Vim instance running with the ECLIPSE servername.

Comment: I used the first approach with runVim (http://www.fastnlight.com/runvim/) and that got me to the right place (couldn't get the second way working on OSX)

Comment: For binding this to a particular shortcut, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8176077/26510

Comment: @Joe You would use /usr/bin/mvim as the path in step 4, assuming you're using MacVim with the associated command-line tool

Comment: Step 5. I like to set up Working directory : ${container_loc} to set it to $resource_loc's directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a small shell script that simply opens whatever options are passed to it in named vim instance. For example, the shell script I use is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

gvim --servername eclipse --remote-tab-silent "$@"
```

Then make the script executable and follow the canonical method described by sleepynate, using your script as the external editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware there is a highly upvoted answer but I should say that what I found most convienent on OSX was to use [QuickCursor](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor) to let me open *any* text in macVim.