# Eclipse: Error "Variable references empty selection: ${resource_loc}"

Tags: eclipse

I have found that using the Eclipse "external tools" launch configuration is the best way to open my favorite editor on the current file in Eclipse,  notably offering a one-time and super-flexible configuration versus the "Open With" menu, which I had tried to use beforehand and always found wanting, constraining, limiting, and requiring repetitive work for many file types. I set up this external tool as follows and this works great for files in my project:

- Run:External Tools:External Tools Configurations...
- New launch configuration
- On the "Build" tab, un-check "Build before Launch"
- On the Common tab, check "External Tools" under the "Display in favorites menu"
- On the Main tab, enter "/usr/bin/myeditor" for the Location
- Under "Working Directory" I am able to leave this blank
- Under arguments ${resource_loc}
- (At the top, in the "Name" field whatever I want the name to show up as)

I originally found this general technique for launching an external editor [right here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084114/how-do-you-open-an-external-vim-editor-containing-the-active-eclipse-editor-file).

So you can see ${resource_loc} or ${resource_path} is the one and only variable I need for this to work, and it does work great when I open a file located inside my Eclipse project and click the external tool. That part is fine.

But the problem I have just discovered occurs when I open a file that is not specifically listed in my project and then click the external tool button. It no longer works and I get an error dialog saying: "Variable references empty selection: ${resource_loc}."

Specifically, to reproduce this, I can create a new C++ "Hello World" project (CDT is included in my Eclipse along with Java) then add the line `#include "/tmp/whatever.h"` at the top of the one cpp file in the project and then right-click on "/tmp/whatever.h" and use the command "Open Declaration" and Eclipse kindly opens the file `/tmp/whatever.h`. Finally, I invoke my external tool intending to view `whatever.h` in my editor, and bang, that's when the problem occurs. (Before doing this I put a harmless line of commented text into `/tmp/whatever.h`.)

Before some SOer asks, no I am not actually trying to `#include "/tmp/whatever.h"`. I am using this `#include` example as a specific way to show how the error can be reproduced. If you must know, in my case I actually observed the error when trying to open the editor while using Eclipse to browse framework files, files that are not part of my project.

I have already tried ${resource_path} to see if maybe that might have something in it in this context, but same error, and I have looked at the documented list of Eclipse launch variables [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm) and again I don't see anything that looks like it would be more well-defined in the context of a file that is not part of the current project.

My assessment right now is that this is an unsolvable problem and likely just a limitation of trying to use the "External Tools" for this editor launching business. I only settled on that after using the default "Open With" menu in Eclipse for a while and finding the whole setup there highly unsatisfactory and requiring repeated configuration and actually IIRC it just would not work at all I believe in the context of my editor and controlling how many windows are created, whether one or many or one per project etc. Above, I simplified the launch for demonstration purposes.

OS: GNU/Linux Xubuntu 15.10.

Eclipse: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) Build id: 20150924-1200

Comment: It is not so much in the current project as in the current Workspace. I don't think any of the variable resolution works for objects outside of the workspace.

Comment: So you don't see any workaround? Isn't it rather odd that there's not a variable among all of them representing the file that's currently open and frontmost in the editor, be it in a project or not? The external tools configuration I have described is not connected to the project of course; it is global and across all projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent the "Workspace is the top-most Eclipse place" rule by *linking* files (or folders for that matter) in a project.

Example:

1. Create a new project:

   *File* → *New* → *Project* → *General* → *Project* → <kbd>Next</kbd> → *Project name:* LinkProject → <kbd>Finish</kbd>
2. Create a file `outside-workspace` anywhere outside your Eclipse workspace dir.
3. Import this file as link:

   Select LinkProject → *File* → *Import...* → *General* → *File System* → <kbd>Next ></kbd> → *From directory:* <as chosen for the file above> → Check ☑️  `outside-workspace`→ (⚠️ The next can be overlooked easily!) <kbd>Advanced >></kbd> → Check ☑️ *Create links in workspace* → <kbd>Finish</kbd>

NB: I doesn't matter whether you uncheck  ☐ *Create link locations relative to:* <kbd>PROJECT_LOC     ˅</kbd>  or what you select from the list. `${resource_loc}` is always the same. Just the file's/folder's *Properties* → *Location:* changes. There is a new property for linked files/folders: *Resolved location* which shows what `${resource_loc}` is resolved to: an [FQFN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name#Filenames_and_paths).

And, once you linked a file/folder in your project it *is* part of your project and you can also access it relatively, e.g. with `${workspace_loc:/LinkProject/outside-workspace}'` which resolves to the FQFN, too.

See also [*Eclipse Platform User Guide – Linked resources*](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-13.htm?cp=0_2_1_2).