# How to repeat input in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to make a separator in code with (for example) 50 '#' chars like that:

```
##################################################
```

In vim or emacs it can be done by "repeat input" feature.

Do you know any way to repeat a character n-times in Eclipse? (would be great without plugins)

Comment: You can just open it in vim and 'y50l' to copy the character.  I keep open both vim and eclipse

Comment: yeeeeeeeeees, of course...but i work 90% of time in Eclipse, so switching to vim is not realy what i want.

Comment: I also work like you. But I always keep a console open and it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options would include installing a VIM plugin for eclipse as answered in this question : [What vim plugins are available for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220653/what-is-the-best-vim-plugin-for-eclipse)

OR,

A very simple **[AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/)** script would do this beautifully :

The code I just tested that would do this is :

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode 2

Hotkey, IfWinActive,ahk_class SWT_Window0 
    Hotkey,#r,repeatchar
    Hotkey,!+^r,repeatchar
return

repeatchar:
    sendinput ^c ;copy the selected character
    sendinput {%clipboard% 50}
return
```

This script would repeat the selected string 50 times in Eclipse on pressing `Windows + R` or `Alt + Ctrl + Shift + R`.

I have shared the script as well as an executable for it **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kkr8iza99yzj7b2/4hRjI3mDVX)**. The executable was created by compiling the script. If you are uncomfortable executing it, you can download the portable version of AHK from **[here](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/)**. With the portable version, you will have to manually associate the `.ahk` files to Open with `AutoHotkey.exe`.

**[Here](http://youtu.be/2XzlaJqPpFE)** is a (not-so-great) screen-cast showing this in action.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an alternative without any plugin. Input the <kbd>#</kbd> character at some place and select it. Now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to open Find/Replace, select the "Regular Expressions" option and use `$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0$0`
as replacement string. It will replace the search term by 50 times itself. As the dialog remembers all entries, you can easily reuse that pattern the next time.