# Vi plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most useable VI/Vim plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766067/what-is-the-most-useable-vi-vim-plugin-for-eclipse)

I have seen a few vi plugins for eclipse. Can anyone suggest which one is the best (not buggy, maintained easy to install...)?

Thanks,
Marko

Comment: A `vi` plugin for eclipse? Why not just use `vi` ?

Comment: Because Eclipse is incredibly powerful at analysing your code base, determining dependencies and allowing refactoring. I'm a fan of vi, but it can't really compete with Eclipse in these areas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) to be the best one. It is free and does a very good job of providing the most important features of vi/Vim. 
As I have checked a minute ago it is still developed.

Comment: It's good but the lack of an actual regular expression engine is a pretty big hole.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [viplugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) to be sufficiently powerful and robust that I've paid for it. It's not often I would say that!

Answer (score 0):

I used a bunch of them and my definitely favorite is http://viableplugin.com/ .  It's not free, but it actually works like real VIM.  In Vrapper you can't search and replace properly, and simple commands like capital-P are subtly different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using both, [viable](http://viableplugin.com/) and [viplugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) and i like both of them. Both are commercial plugins and both are more than just worth the 15 Eruros. Right now I prefer viplugin, as there's a lot of development going on lately (a new version is released once a week).